# identity_insert в динамическом запросе 2019

Tags: sql-server, insert, temporary-table

В 2019м сервере перестал работать данный код

```
BEGIN TRAN
CREATE table #TempTable(Id INT PRIMARY KEY, Val INT IDENTITY(1,1))

DECLARE @Sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'
SET identity_insert #TempTable ON;
INSERT INTO #TempTable(Id, Val) VALUES (1, 1);
INSERT INTO #TempTable(Id, Val) VALUES (2, 2);
'

EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @Sql

SELECT * FROM #TempTable

ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
```

ошибка:
*Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table '#TempTable' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.*

В более ранних версиях всё работало. Что-то поменялось?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58881678/sql-server-2019-behavior-change-with-scope-of-set-identity-insert-on-off